# SHA-1 hashing not working in jboss form based authentication using custom REALM

Tags: java, security, authentication, jboss

In my application passwords are encrypted using SHA-1,

```
public static  String passwordEncryption(String password){

   MessageDigest md =null;
    try {
        md= MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     md.update(password.getBytes());
     byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();

     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

     for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) {
          sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

And i m using Jboss form based authentication having custom realm, now problem is that it is not logging in user even with right password, it redirects to error page everytime.

my realm in standalone.xml is

```
 <security-domain name="testRealm" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/sbos"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWORD FROM USER WHERE NAME = ?"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-1"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT 'Manager','Manager' FROM user WHERE name = ?"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default value of hashEncoding is base64. you have to solved this by changing hashEncoding to hex because SHA-1 uses hexadecimal encoding.

```
<module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-1"/>
<module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add an audit element to your security-domain as follows:

```
    <audit>
        <provider-module code="LogAuditProvider"/>
    </audit>
```

Then add the following under subsystem logging, if not already there:

```
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="AUDIT" autoflush="true">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="audit.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="org.jboss.security">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="AUDIT"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
```

Then you can check the audit.log for more details about your error.